# Returning multiple different values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get both values while compiling? It is only returning 129.

```
def nestedListSum(NL):
    if isinstance(NL, int):
        return NL

    o=NL*2
    return o
    # some examples
print(nestedListSum(129))
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all values that you want to return in a single `return` statement:

```
def nestedListSum(NL):
    if isinstance(NL, int):
        o = NL * 2
        return NL, o
print(nestedListSum(129))
```

This returns a tuple `(129, 258)`.